# SQL: How to select a column-value based on an aggregate min/max value in a window frame (including preceding rows)

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have the following table:

```
| Date     | Value   | Name | AnticipatedValue |
| -------- | ------- | ---- | ---------------- |
| 27.11.20 | 639.600 | col1 |                  |
| 30.11.20 | 638.300 | col2 |                  |
| 01.12.20 | 638.000 | col3 | col1             |
| 02.12.20 | 642.600 | col4 | col1             |
| 03.12.20 | 646.200 | col5 | col1             |
| 04.12.20 | 651.900 | col6 | col4             |
| 07.12.20 | 651.800 | col7 | col4             |
| 08.12.20 | 643.800 | col8 | col6             |
| 09.12.20 | 654.250 | col9 | col6             |
```

I want the **name** from the row that has the max **value** between the 2nd and 5th **preceding** row. The column **AnticipatedValue** shows my desired result.

I am currently using a window function to get the max **value** in that example, however I am missing a way to get the corresponding **name** of that max **value**.
My current code looks like this:

```sql
MAX(value) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 2 PRECEDING)
```

I think what would help me most would be if I were able to do another ORDER BY **inside** of the window frame itself. Then I could just use an order by descending by value and take the first name that I get. However this isn't possible / implement yet in aggregate functions in sql.

Also using a subquery to get the corresponding name is quite difficult imo, as I would still have to apply the window frame (i.e. preceding 2nd and 5th row) inside of the subquery.

I am using Postgres 12.6.

I would highly appreciate any help regarding this sql riddle. I feel that I am not far from the solution, but couldn't find any elegant way to do it.

**Update**
I took Gordon Linoff's solution and adjusted it by using a left join and adding a limit 1 to get the above table that I desired:

```sql
select t.*, t2.*
from t left join lateral
     (select t2.name, t2.value
      from (select t2.name, t2.value
            from t t2
            where t2.date < t.date
            order by t2.date desc
            offset 1 fetch first 4 rows only
           ) t2
       order by value desc
      limit 1
      ) t2 ON true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.*, t2.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from (select t2.name, t2.value
            from t t2
            where t2.date < t.date
            order by t2.date desc
            offset 1 fetch first 4 rows only
           ) t2
       order by value desc
      ) t2;
```

Comment: You are the only person I know who uses lateral joins in their answers.  Fantastic.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff
This sql riddle has been haunting me for days now while I was reading through all kind of window function content and such, desperately searching for something I overlooked. And here you come with your lateral cross join and smart way of using a negative offset with the where clause + descending order by...fantastic, thanks a lot!! Very much to learn for me from that statement
PS: I guess there was no elegant way of solving it with a window function, right?!

Comment: So I have been working with this solution but realized that the performance of my overall query is greatly reduced (it is taking several seconds now). Is there any more efficient way available, or this kind of query always rather inefficient? Thanks a lot in advance for any advice